# Highstock / Highcharts scrollbar should control 2 charts

Tags: highcharts

I've an interesting problem with Highstock library. I've 2 stock charts on my page. Both of them have line-charts which span more than the width of the HTML.

I now need to control the movement of both the charts using a scrollbar that is there on one chart - which means chronologically aligning both the charts.

Has anyone tried something like this before? If yes, I only need to know if this is possible and how so that I can try myself out.

Otherwise, we could brainstorm over this problem together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `afterSetExtremes` to get new extremes for one chart, compare with second chart extremes, and set that extremes if are different.

Comment: I tried looking up afterSetExtremes. I understand that I can get extremes from this. I will try looking this up and let you know if I'm able to find a solution. Thanks a lot!